# mysql-connector-python 8.0.33 has requirement protobuf<=3.20.3,>=3.11.0, but you have protobuf 4.23.1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-data-fusion

Using GCP Cloud Composer,trying to add PyPI package `google-cloud-data-fusion`

[image]

Version used:  composer-2.2.0-airflow-2.5.1

Issue: trying to add PYPI "google-cloud-data-fusion" and it's throwing the error.

UPDATE operation on this environment failed Just now with the following error message:
Failed to install PyPI packages. mysql-connector-python 8.0.33 has requirement protobuf<=3.20.3,>=3.11.0, but you have protobuf 4.23.1.

I have tried to update some of the dependent packages but found some of the packages are having dependency issue and can not find any solution for this.

1. google-cloud-data-fusion 1.8.1 has requirement protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.0.
2. mysql-connector-python 8.0.33 has requirement protobuf<=3.20.3,>=3.11.0, but you have protobuf 4.23.1.
3. google-ads 20.0.0+composer has requirement proto-plus==1.19.6, but you have proto-plus 1.22.2.
4. google-ads 21.1.0 has requirement protobuf>=4.21.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.3.
5. google-ads 21.0.0 has requirement protobuf>=4.21.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.3.

Dependepent packages can be found here for specified composer version.
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions

Comment: Where are you installing (desktop or cloud)? Edit you post with relevant environment details.

Comment: Your update is too cryptic. Show exactly what you are doing that generates the problem. For example, how are the packages being specified and installed? You have package collisions from several different major packages such as google-ads and mysql-connector-python.

Answer (score 2):

Replicated your case and got the same error message:
[image]

The error is due to package dependency. After downgrading and upgrading packages such as protfus,protoplus..etc not solved the issue. It seems like an internal issue.

There is a [similar issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/284325736) filed for the same. You can vote for this issue by clicking the "+1" and "STAR" mark to receive updates on it or you can also create a new request thread in Google’s [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).